# Is it possible to build a target works on ios 4 5 6

Tags: ios

As I know, snow leopard can not do this.
I hope to know if my mac osx is 10.8, which xcode version can to build a target works on ios 4 5 6?
Or I need to downgrade to lion?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, lost 2 days of my life trying to solve this problem for a framework I built: there is NO single version of Xcode that supports all 3 of the armv6, armv7 and armv7s architectures, so effectively, there is no way to do what you want.

With Xcode 4.5 you can build a target that works on iOS 4.3 and higher (including 5 and 6) by supporting the armv7 and armv7s architectures.

With Xcode 4.4.1 you can build a target that works on iOS 4.0 up to iOS 5.1 (not iOS 6.0) by supporting the armv6 and armv7 architectures.

It might be possible if you have both installed to script the building of an armv6 target with Xcode 4.4.1, then an armv7/armv7s target with Xcode 4.5 and then merge them using **lipo** but that seems like it would be quite difficult.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I deal with app, submit another app? or there is a way to run different target after recognizing os version?

Comment: The official recommended way is "stop supporting armv6" since it is getting pretty old now.